# Subir imagen desde SD - GeneXus

Tags: genexus

Necesito subir imágenes desde una app (Android e iOS) al servidor (IIS) y poder manipularlas luego.
Las estoy enviando como parámetro en un procedure REST y con esto logro que se copien en el directorio *PrivateTempStorage*, pero lo hace con un nombre aleatorio que no encuentro manera de recuperar. Cuando el directorio está vacío, las nombra "blob.jpeg"; las siguientes las nombra por ej. "blob3a5e4c09-72e8-4263-9ca2-0a6d9adf60ab.jpeg".

Actualmente obtengo la imagen desde la galería con *PhotoLibrary*. He probado utilizar el external object *Files*, pero no consigo mejor resultado.

Estoy trabajando con GeneXus 17 U2 compilando en .NET y sin base de datos (sólo GAM).

¿Se les ocurre algo?

Gracias!

Comment: Hola Fabricio, te hago un par de preguntas para ver si puedo ayudarte:

1- ¿La app SD es online u offline?

2- ¿Cuál sería el caso de uso? es decir, una vez que obtienes la imagen ¿Que quieres hacer con ella?

Comment: Buenas tardes @Marcelito! La app es online y la idea es manipular la imagen del lado del servidor con un external object (leer un QR).
Ya conseguí una solución, igualmente gracias por la disposición. Tenías algo mas en mente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente la solución fue convertir la imagen a base64 del lado del cliente, pasarlo al servidor y allí levantarlo en un Blob, con el cual puedo trabajar libremente.
Para convertir la imagen a base64, utilicé el método *ImageToBase64* del objeto *SmartDevicesPlusUtil* (es necesario tener SD+).

Es útil solo para imágenes de tamaño pequeño, ya que el varchar generado podría ser muy extenso y el servicio web generaría un timeout.